# Is there any rule/way to automatically create folder on the basis of date in outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, rules, inbox

Let me elaborate the title. Suppose today is `11-23-2015`(EST Standards MM-DD-YYYY). First mail comes and then automatically a folder will be created with name `11-23-2015` and all mail will be stored in that folder for this specific day.

Again on the next day a folder will be created with name as `11-24-2015` and all mails will be stored on that folder.

I am not concerned about the date-format, but I need a way to divide incoming mails by date automatically. I am using **Outlook 2007**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic email sorting in Outlook 2013?](http://superuser.com/questions/819042/dynamic-email-sorting-in-outlook-2013)

Comment: I don't think it is really a duplicate since the date received and subject are significantly different. However, since answers might be very similar (use scripting and parse as required) it might be OK to close as dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can create a VBA macro that creates (or checks for existance of) the folder and moves the incoming message into this folder. Then you'll be able to execute this macro in Outlook rule.